# Memory usage of a process in a shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-script, sh

I want to find out the memory usage of a process in a shell script.I tried to use this piece of code :

```
while[process] do
    if [ -e /proc/$pidno/statm ]; then
    m=`awk '{OFS="\t";print $1,$2,$3,$6}' /proc/$pidno/statm`
    perc=`top -bd .10 -p $pidno -n 1 | grep $pidno | gawk '{print \$10}'`
    echo -e "$m\t$perc"
    else
    echo "$pidno is not running"
    fi
done
```

but I cannot seem to access /proc as I am not running the command as root. I don't have right to be the root. Can you please help, how can I make this work or any other method to get the memory usage.

I have the PID of the process.

Answer (score 0):

The ps command is your best bet, eg. `ps u$pidno` will tell you virtual process size and resident-set size.